# CSS TransitionEnd not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a very basic test for a CSS keyframe animation, including an event listener for 'ontransitionend' - but this 'transition end' listener just won't fire, no matter what variation I use. (my complete code has all the vendor prefixes).

HTML

```
<div id="block">I like to move it</div>
```

CSS

```
.tweetanimation {
    -webkit-animation: Tweet_FadeInOut 6s 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Tweet_FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    left:30%;
  }
  30%, 70% {
    opacity:1;
    left:15%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left:0%;
  }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#block").one('webkitTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
        alert("block has finished moving");
});

$("#block").addClass("tweetanimation");
```

For some reason, I can't get it to work! What am I missing?
[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/n6xmhLc5/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you aren't using the `transition` property at all instead you are using the keyframe animation. You need `animationend`:

```
$("#block").one('webkitAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
    alert("block has finished moving");
});
$("#block").addClass("tweetanimation");
```

#### [DemoFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6xmhLc5/2/)      <kbd>and</kbd>    [More Info Link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end)

Comment: Argh! I must have been staring at my code for too long! Thanks for pointing this out.